# List is asked to pass some of its items and skip others but its stopping in the first few items

Tags: python

So the objetive is that the list names sorted_resistances appends its first 12 items to the blocks_A[0] and then skip 12 items and pass the next 12 to the blocks_A[1] and so on until the length of blocks_A[28] equals 12. The problem is that its only doing blocks_A[1] and it stops but doesnt give an error.

```
from math import *

blocks_B = []
y = 0
while y < 29:
    y = y + 1
    block_y = []
    blocks_B.append(block_y)

blocks_A = []
y = 0
while y < 29:
    y = y + 1
    block_y = []
    blocks_A.append(block_y)

with open("file.txt") as file_in:

    list_of_resistances = []
    for line in file_in:
        list_of_resistances.append(int(line))
        sorted_resistances = sorted(list_of_resistances)

    z = 0
    w = 11
    x = 0
    for y in sorted_resistances[z:w]:
        blocks_A[x].append(y)
        blocks_A[x].sort()
        if len(blocks_A[x]) == 12:
            x = x + 1
            z = z + 24
            w = w + 24
        if len(blocks_A[28]) == 12:
            break


print(blocks_A)
print(blocks_B)
```

Comment: What is in the file being read?

Comment: @ScottHunter it's just a list of 900 numbers

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your problem lies in this block:

```
    for y in sorted_resistances[z:w]:
        blocks_A[x].append(y)
        blocks_A[x].sort()
        if len(blocks_A[x]) == 12:
            x = x + 1
            z = z + 24
            w = w + 24
        if len(blocks_A[28]) == 12:
            break
```

You are expecting that by changing z and w inside the loop, that a new loop with new z and w values is started. That is not happening. You should use two nexsted loops:

```
while len(blocks_A[28]) < 12:
    # set x, z, w to initial values
    for y in sorted_resistances[z:w]:
        # Your inside loop
    # set x, z, w to new values
```

A couple other notes:
You can concatenate two lists with + and thus save yourself some explicit loops:

```
blocks_A[x] += sorted_resistances[z:w]
blocks_A[x].sort() # Sorting once is more efficient than sorting after each element
```

Your initial code for creating a list of empty lists can be written much shorter. Instead of

```
blocks_A = []
y = 0
while y < 29:
    y = y + 1
    block_y = []
    blocks_A.append(block_y)
```

the below will do the same in one line:

```
blocks_A = [ [] for _ in range(29) ]
```

Finally, if you learn a bit more on how to write proper python code, you can do it in 3 lines:

```
>>> with open("file.txt") as fp:
...     list_of_resistances = sorted([int(line.strip()) for line in fp])
...
>>> block_A = [list_of_resistances[12*x:12*(x+1)] for x in range(0, 58, 2)]
>>> len(block_A)
29
>>> block_A[0]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
>>> block_A[1]
[25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36]
>>> block_A[28]
[673, 674, 675, 676, 677, 678, 679, 680, 681, 682, 683, 684]
```

My `file.txt` contained each number from 1 to 900 once.

Comment: I tried that and the loop seems to be infinite now